# Nginx web-cache tweeking

Tags: nginx, cache

I am trying to set up an NGINX server to act as a caching server for an underlying PHP application sitting on another server. In principle, things are working great but because of some "bad behaviour" of the PHP application, I need to set up some tweaks on NGINX, but which until now I failed in succeeding. Is there a solution for these issues?

Problem 1:
The PHP application is sending "Vary: Accept-Encoding" as a response header for cacheable content and causing NGINX to retain a different cache copy for different Accept-Encoding request header, which is correct but not as I would like it to behave. My needs require that NGINX removes the Accept-Encoding request header as it proxies to the PHP application and ignores the header when it comes to caching.

I've achieved the first part by using:

```
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
```

This configuration removes the header from the request but it will not ignore it in terms of caching. 
I am well aware of proxy_ignore_headers and that I can use it in the below setup but such as solution will ignore any header name in the Vary header and not only Accept-Encoding

```
 proxy_ignore_headers Vary;
```

Is there a solution to this issue?

Problem 2:

The PHP application is trying to set session cookies for cacheable content. I wish NGINX to ignore the Set-Cookie header for caching, but also remove the response header Set-Cookie for any cacheable content.

To make NGINX ignore the Set-Cookie response header in terms of cache I used:

```
 proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
```

NGINX does ignore the header, but it will send the Set-Cookie response header to any user hitting the cache. Is there a solution on NGINX whereby I can remove a header based on if a page is being cached or not.

I tried using the if clause to check the $sent_http_cache_control variable but it seems that if statements are not re-run after the response is available and so such variables would not be set while if is being evaluated.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_hide_header should help with second problem

Comment: How do I tell NGINX to remove header only if the item is cacheable?